# Google Maps Marker not getting displayed

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I am trying to learn google map API. I see a map but I am unable to get a marker at the right location. I see it somewhere in the ocean near China. Moreover, map is centered at (0,0) and not the (lat,long) that I have provided. Here is my code

**Activity**

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_page);
        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
                .title("San Francisco"));
    }

}
```

**home_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="My SHA1 key"/>
    </application>
```

What am I missing out?

Comment: did you try extending FragmentActivity instead of Activity?

Comment: Show us manifest file.

Comment: I see the marker somewhere in the ocean near China. Moreover, map is centered at (0,0) and not the (lat,long) that I have provided which should be San Francisco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lat, long of San Francisco is `37.7833° N, 122.4167° W` according to Google. A longitude on the West should be indicated with a negative sign. So the coordinates should have been something like     `37.7750, -122.4183`

Answer (score 4):

I think, you need to set icon to show marker. So, added .icon and set your own marker icon or use default icon.

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
                .title("San Francisco").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

Comment: I have added a bit more info. Map is centered at 0,0 and not at the lat,long that I have provided.

Comment: Map is centered at 0,0. What do you means?, Explain more.

Comment: When the activity loads, I see a map. But it shows Atlantic ocean at 0,0 as the default (lat,lon). The coordinates that I gave does not appear. So the problem is not just with the marker icon but the entire marker object itself.

Comment: Check your  LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183) is valid in google map.

Comment: Ah. I see, when I do a regular google search I get this lat,long for San Francisco. But when I search in google maps, it points to the same  spot on ocean.

Answer (score 0):

Initially your `GoogleMap` can takes times to load. So just check by this.

```
 if(map!=null) {

   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
            .title("San Francisco"));

 }
```

Comment: But its on the same thread. If my map object was null then, I would have got a NullPointerException when I say map.addMarker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zoomToSpan`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController)

This will set center to your location. I think this what you need.