# Google Map appears at default location (0,0) markers and current location not showing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Looking to implement a map that will zoom to a specific location that display multiple markers and users current location.

Map appears centered at (0,0) with no markers. 
Have searched for answers for hours - Have tried over and over for 2 days!!

Please any feedback is appreciated!

SupportMapFragmentActivity.java

```
          public class SupportMapFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static View view;
private SupportMapFragment fMap;
private static Double latitude, longitude;
GoogleMap map;

public SupportMapFragmentActivity() {
}



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.supportmapfragment, container, false);
    latitude = 26.78;
    longitude = 72.56;
    FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    if (fMap != null); {
       fMap = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fMap).commit();
        fMap.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map = map;

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new
            LatLng(49.39, -124.83), 20));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
            .title("San Francisco")
            .snippet("Population: 776733"));
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
     map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution here in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876633/google-maps-marker-not-getting-displayed), as you both try to show the markers in San Francisco.

The solution is change the longitude to negative(-) coordinates. Because longitude on the West side is indicated a negative sign.

Also from your problem regarding the location service. I think this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/) can help you on how your application will show your current location.